# Desabilitar campo multine com Jquery no Sharepoint

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

estou realizando um script em Jquery para desabilitar certos campos de uma página no Sharepoint, os campos de uma linha que identifiquei de uma linha são inputs e o multilines parece que são divs.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que o input de uma linha está desabilitado com o código que eu fiz, mas o abaixo  que é multiline eu consigo realizar edição e não quero isso.

﻿
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Inspecionei o campo e ele me retornou o código html acima, logo fiz o seguinte script para tentar desabilitar:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[id='o id da div']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#CDC5BF');
       $("select[id='id da div']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Ainda não está funciionando...

Conseguem me auxiliar nisso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Olá @V. Medeiros sua pergunta está inconsistente, `DIV` são elementos somente leitura, não faz sentido "desabilita-los" deve haver um elemento dentro da div mostrada no print um `TEXTAREA` este que você deve manipular em seu codigo JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Obrigado Vinicius pelo toque, ainda sou iniciante!

Analisei o código e tentei manipular o elemento e ainda sem sucesso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("textarea[id='id do textarea']").attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#D3D3D3');
           $("select[id='id do text area']").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```